# DHCPPloc.exe or equivalent for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, dhcp

There seems to be some DHCP funnyness going on so I need to run something to show me what's going at a DHCP level. Before I upgraded my machine to Windows 7 I used DHCPloc.exe from the Windows XP support tools, and it worked like a charm.

I can't seem to find Support Tools for Windows 7, and trying to use the XP tools in compatibility mode doesn't work (I tried, it fails to open a receiving socket).

I need a tool to monitor DHCP traffic, and ideally one that lets me filter it to exclude DHCP traffic from our trusted DHCP servers and only show me un-authorised DHCP traffic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still use DHCPloc.exe on Windows 7:

1. Download "Windows XP Service Pack 2 Support Tools" from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18546).
2. Right-click on the executable and select Properties->Compatibility
   then turn on Compatibility Mode and set it to "Windows XP (Service
   Pack 3)".
3. Install as normal.

DHCPLoc.exe works fine on my Win7 x64 installation.

Comment: Doesn't work on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

Since DHCP traffic is broadcast based you should be able to run a packet capture somewhere on your network and see it. Try installing Wireshark or Microsoft Network Monitor on your Windows 7 machine, start a capture, and filter for DHCP traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this technique to open DHCPLoc.exe on newer Windows versions.

1. Download "Windows XP Service Pack 2 Support Tools" from [here][1].
2. Open the downloaded file - WindowsXP-KB838079-SupportTools-ENU.exe - using 7-zip.
3. DHCPLoc.exe is contained within the "support.cab" file.